# Submitting the form always calls get action method instead of post action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I've got the following code in my controller (asp.net 4.5.1 mvc 5) that allows a user to register on my site. Everything was working fine but Ive added another controller and another service and now when ever I try to register all it does on submit is redirect back to the form blank again. After debugging, the post action method in controller below is never called

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            UserManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, model.FirstName));
            var service = new GRCMemberService(HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>());
            service.CreateGRCMember(model.FirstName, model.LastName, model.Address1, model.Address2, model.City, model.County, model.Postcode, model.Telephone, model.DateOfBirth, model.Dietary, model.CompLicenceNo, model.SelectedLicenceTypeId, model.NOKFirstName, model.NOKLastName, model.NOKTelephone, model.RelationshipTypeId, model.OtherOrgsGRC, model.OtherClubEvents, model.OtherOrgsOutside, user.Id);
            //var currentUser = UserManager.FindByName(user.Id);
            //var newrole = ("GRCMember");
            //var roleresult = UserManager.AddToRole(currentUser.Id, newrole);
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

            // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
            // Send an email with this link
            // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
            // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }  
        AddErrors(result);
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form 
    return View(model); 
}
```

instead, the get action method below is always called every time I submit the form:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    return View();
}
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Below is my ViewModel and View code.

**ViewModel**

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [StringLength(160, ErrorMessage = "First Name cannot be longer than 160 characters.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [StringLength(160, ErrorMessage = "Last Name cannot be longer than 160 characters.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Address 1")]
    [StringLength(160, ErrorMessage = "Address1 cannot be longer than 160 characters.")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address 2")]
    [StringLength(160, ErrorMessage = "Address2 cannot be longer than 160 characters.")]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "City cannot be longer than 100 characters.")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "County")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "County cannot be longer than 100 characters.")]
    public string County { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "PostCode")]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Postcode cannot be longer than 10 characters.")]
    public string Postcode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Telephone")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Telephone cannot be longer than 20 characters.")]
    public string Telephone { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Competition Licence Number cannot be longer than 20 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Licence Number")]
    public string CompLicenceNo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Licence Type")]
    public int? SelectedLicenceTypeId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Competition Licence Number cannot be longer than 20 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Dietary Requirements - For events")]
    public string Dietary { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Next of Kin Name cannot be longer than 100 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Next of kin First Name")]
    public string NOKFirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Next of Kin Name cannot be longer than 100 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Next of kin Last Name")]
    public string NOKLastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Next of Kin Telephone cannot be longer than 20 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Next of kin Telephone")]
    public string NOKTelephone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Next of kin Relationship")]
    public int? RelationshipTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Allow other organisations on Grass Roots Clicks to contact you?")]
    public bool OtherOrgsGRC { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Allow other clubs you are a member of or ones whose events you enter to contact you?")]
    public bool OtherClubEvents { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Allow other organisations outside of Grass Roots Clicks that we are working with to contact you?")]
    public bool OtherOrgsOutside { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm email")]
    [Compare("Email", ErrorMessage = "Your email and confirmation email do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model GRCWebApp.Models.RegisterViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2 class="text-success">@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="well bs-component">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <fieldset>
                    <section id="loginForm">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            <hr />
                            @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                            <h3 class="text-success col-md-offset-1">Name &amp; Address</h3>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3  col-md-offset-1">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "John" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Smith" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "1 Apple Road" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-5">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Neighbourhood" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Some Town" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-5">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.County, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.County, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Someshire" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.County, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Postcode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Postcode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "AA1 2BB" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Postcode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="text-success col-md-offset-1">Contact Details</h3>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Telephone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telephone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "01234 567890" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telephone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "me@provider.com" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmEmail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "me@provider.com" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="text-success col-md-offset-1">Competition Licence</h3>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompLicenceNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompLicenceNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "123456" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompLicenceNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedLicenceTypeId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedLicenceTypeId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedLicenceTypeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="text-success col-md-offset-1">Personal Details</h3>
                            <h4 class="text-success col-md-offset-1">Why do we need this information?</h4>
                            <p>To make it easier for you to enter events here on Grass Roots Clicks we gatther certain information that we can then populate into your entry. Why do we need a date of birth? Organisers gain great benefit form knowing what ages are taking part in their events. We dont share your date of birth, we use your current age to help the organisers and also tailor the entry form to you e.g. if your under 18 we'll ask you for parental permission for some events.</p>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "01/12/80" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NOKFirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NOKFirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Jane" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NOKFirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NOKLastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NOKLastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Smith" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NOKLastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NOKTelephone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NOKTelephone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "07234 567890" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NOKTelephone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RelationshipTypeId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RelationshipTypeId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RelationshipTypeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dietary, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dietary, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Vegetarian" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dietary, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="text-success col-md-offset-1">Password</h3>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="text-success col-md-offset-1">Contact</h3>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OtherOrgsGRC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.OtherOrgsGRC, new { @checked = "checked" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OtherOrgsGRC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OtherClubEvents, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.OtherClubEvents, new { @checked = "checked" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OtherClubEvents, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OtherOrgsOutside, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.OtherOrgsOutside, new { @checked = "checked" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OtherOrgsOutside, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </section>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4 panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title " align="center">Use another service to register</h3>
        </div>

        @Html.Partial("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", new GRCWebApp.Models.ExternalLoginListViewModel { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })

    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#DateOfBirth").datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        startDate: "-120y",
        endDate: "-10y",
        startView: 2,
        calendarWeeks: true,
        defaultViewDate: { year: 1975, month: 01, day: 01 }
    });
    </script>
    }
```

Comment: What does `AddErrors(result)` do?

Comment: as its code I've copied from a tutorial I'm afraid I don't know, I did take it out and nothing changed

Comment: heres the definition for it

Comment: private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
            }
        }

Comment: Your controller code is not complete. Is there any code after the `if (ModelState.IsValid)` block? The cause could be that `ModelState.IsValid` is false, or `result.Succeeded` is false.

Comment: yes sorry its this             // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

Comment: as Im sure you've guessed I'm new to this and don't know how to debug why the model isn't valid

Comment: Try to change `@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })` to `@Html.ValidationSummary(false)` and see if you get any error message.

Comment: sadly not it just returns the view blank again with all the values in the query string url

Comment: Can you make sure if this line isn't commented/removed: `AddErrors(result);` ?

Comment: same result with AddErrors(result); commented out

Comment: Have you tried to debug and put a break point inside your controller method? You need to check if `ModelState.IsValid` is false or `result.Succeeded` is false.

Comment: I've added break points and everytime i press the submit button it goes to the break point in the get method in the controller not the post

Comment: What does the get controller method look like? Can you add the code to your question?

Comment: very simple not action other than the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by removing the form, fieldset and section tags at the beginning of the view.

Thanks to ekad for helping debug the problem

Comment: In other words, nested forms are invalid. See here for more info: [Can you nest html forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/379610/1905949)